# Mercurial - merging same changeset to a repository twice?

Tags: mercurial, merge

We have these Mercurial repositories:

```
Trunk
|
|
|---------myapp_1_0_23 (created off release 1.0.23)    
|
|---------myapp-newstuff (created off rel 2.0.4)
```

Release schedule (nothing yet released):

- v1.0 from `myapp_1.0.23`, any add'l changes in this repo will get merged to the trunk
- v2.0 from the trunk
- v3.0 or v4.0 released based on a merge of `myapp-newstuff` and the trunk. At the time of the merge the trunk may have v2.0 code or some new features that we'll release from the trunk as v3.0

After making changes in `myapp_1.0.23`, we merge them to the trunk, but let's say we also need them in `myapp-newstuff` so we also merge them there.  What then happens when we eventually merge `myapp-newstuff` code to the trunk?

The trunk already has changes made in `myapp_1.0.23` so what happens when we merge those same changesets from `myapp-newstuff` back to the trunk?  Will Mercurial be smart enough to know those changesets are already in the trunk?

Comment: I ask mostly same question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709365/how-to-move-bugfixes-across-branches-in-dvcs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mercurial will handle this situation just great -- because you're using 'merge'.  When you're using export/import (or transplant), *cherry picking* as it's called, and you have the same changesets in there multiple times with different node ids (due to different parents) then Mercurial can't know "Oh, this one's already here".  However, so long as you're merging Mercurial will do a great job of saying "oh, this repo already has that changeset so I don't need to re-apply it".

The general rule of thumb is: "Make every change with as early a parent as you can and then merge down".  If I have a bug that's in version one, two, and three, I fix it in one and then merge into two and then merge into three.  If instead you fix it first in three, then you have to try to get it into two without bringing all the other changes in version three with it -- which is hard and often requires the very cherry picking we're trying to avoid.

Comment: Thanks Ry4an, how does Mercurial keep track of changesets merged in from other repositories?  Does it use the changeset hash id?  Is this id unique across all repositories?

Comment: As always, the best way to learn Mercurial is to make a local clone or just a copy, and experiment, observing the results.

Comment: Yeah, the node id (hash) is global and used to keep track of what is already there.  @Lasse is correct -- just play around with it on the command line.  You can use dir to dir pushes to test all of this w/o any real effort.